# How to create CSV file in netsuite with base64 content?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am downloading a file from the web, I need to save him in the file cabinet, but when I save it its an empty file (0kb).

```
let response = https.get({
    url: url
});

log.debug('response', JSON.stringify(response.body)) //getting the file content
let fileContent = response.body;
let decodedStr = fileToBase64(fileContent); // get base64 content

let createFile = file.create({
    name: "test.csv",
    fileType: file.Type.CSV,
    content: decodedStr,
    folder: 1000
});

createFile.save();

//get base 64 
function fileToBase64(stringInput) {
    return encode.convert({
        string: stringInput,
        inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
        outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64
    });
}
```

still gets an empty csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if it base64Encoded the file type should not be CSV but file.Type.PLAINTEXT